# $\mathbb{E} \left(|N| \choose k \right)$ at a given time $t$ when $N$ is a unit rate Poisson Point Process, for a fixed positive integer $k$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

Would like someone to double check my work here. Thank you :)

$|N|$ is the number of points of the unit  rate Poisson point process up to time $t$. At time $t$, $|N| \sim Poisson(t)$. Therefore,
$$
\begin{split}
\mathbb{E} \left(|N| \choose k \right) &= \sum_{i=0}^\infty {i \choose k} \mathbb{P}(N = i) \\
&= \sum_{i=k}^\infty{i \choose k} \mathbb{P}(N = i) \\
&= \sum_{i=k}^\infty{i \choose k} \frac{e^{-t} t^i}{i!}\\
&=e^{-t} {1\over k!} t^k\sum_{i=k}^\infty \frac{t^{i-k}}{(i-k)!} \\
&= e^{-t} {1\over k!} t^k e^t \\
&= {t^k \over k!}
\end{split}
$$

Comment: You seem to have calculated $E[\binom{N}{k}\mathbf{1}_{\{N\geq k\}}]$ which in fact makes more sense than $E[\binom{N}{k}]$

Comment: @Snoop I was thinking that $N \choose k$ is $0$ when $N < k$. Not sure if this is the usual convention though.

Comment: But yes I guess implicitly it would only make sense if N≥k